# A word for the meeting place of opposites

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am in search of a word that represents a place or a situation where opposites meet.

The nearest word that I can find for it is the word **horizon** which according to oxford dictionary means "The line at which the earth's surface and the sky appear to meet". My concern here is that horizon signifies the place where they appear to meet, not the place where they actually meet.

Comment: Please can you give us the sentence where you will use this?

Comment: Your use of 'opposite' seems subjective. The word is used with and without precision. Land and sky are only opposites if one chooses a very broad definition. In such cases, 'interface' or even 'join' and synonyms are valid, and the question is not really suitable for ELU.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I want to use it like "a place where fun and savings meet together ". I just want the word to be analogous to situtation. As you can see fun and savings are not opposite words but according to me savings is something that we expect from a mature or an old person and on the other hand fun is usually associated with innocence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I m looking for a broader or an analogous term for the situation as  I have mentioned in above comment.

Comment: I've heard 'where ... and ... collide', if that helps.

Comment: Um... Are you under the impression that the earth's surface and the sky *actually* meet?

Comment: @puppetsock no I am not under that impression. Have a look at my previous comment, you will get the idea of what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some days I'm less happy with www.dictionary.com than others. It calls "apposition" a noun, but then gives the following as the first definition.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/apposition

1 the act of placing together or bringing into proximity; juxtaposition.

So, a noun is an act of placing. OK then. Anyway, how about apposition?

Answer (score 0):

A point where two or more things come together is called a [**convergence**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/convergence).

> The hills converged into a mountain range.

However, from your description in the comments, it sounds like you're looking for the phrase **come together**.  This would be much less formal than *convergence*, for example if used in advertising copy.

> *A place where fun and savings come together.*

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are looking for.  Aristotle, in his *Nichomachean Ethics* offers as a definition of the good “the mean between two extremes”.  For example, he illustrates, courage is the mean between the extremes of cowardice and foolhardiness.

These, of course, are opposites.  But ‘fun’ and ‘savings’ are not opposites in the way ‘cowardice’ and ‘foolhardiness’ are.  The equivalent in relation to ‘savings’ would be (for example) ‘extravagance’ and ‘niggardliness’ or something like that.  ‘Thrift’ might be the ‘happy medium’ between (say) extravagance/self-indulgence on the one hand and niggardliness/self-denial on the other hand.

Perhaps the best word for the mean between these and other extremes is *balance*.